# Why is Ubuntu telling me my drive is full?

Tags: disk, disk-management, helpfile

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu on a 500gb drive however, yesterday as I was downloading some stuff to my downloads folder I got the message that I don't have enough space. When I checked the properties on the folder it told me I had only a few kb's left. How is this possible? It's a 500gb drive and currently apart from the ubuntu install there's only a few gb of stuff on the drive.

More importantly how do i fix it?

Comment: How much space (of the 500GB) have you allocated to Ubuntu? Can you open a terminal window, type `df -h`, hit Enter, add the output to the question above.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of the `df` command.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please provide some more information about your system. Please open your terminal by pressing the keys Ctrl+Alt+T and enter the following commands (after each of the following commands press the Enter key): `df -h`, then `du -hs ~` and then `du -hs ~/*`. Please post output of each of the commands by editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

First, open **Disks** and check how large is your HDD and how it is partitioned.

[image]

Second, open **baobab**, also known as **Disk Usage Analyser**. This program will show you what files/folders are using space and how much.

[image]